# Advance Datagrid view to get filterevent args

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, advanceddatagrid

How to get filtereventargs in advance datagrid view so that i can find which column filter is being applied to .
I have tried add the event dataviewgrid.filterchanged but it gives one system event args
also is there an option to remove clear filter option .

Comment: Please paste code and a few more lines of explanation.

Comment: private void logViewGrid_FilterStringChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: That is the code to capture filter change event ...i want adgv.filtereventargs instead of eventargs generated by system to capture which column filter is applied